# IBM ID in local develommet

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

There is any way to test a local development with IBM App ID? It works fine when you upload the app to bluemix, but I don't found how to make it work in local. Any advice or recommendation? 
PS.I use Node for development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your local environment to use the App ID service. Specifically, you can develop code locally by using the App ID server SDK to send requests to the development server.

See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/protecting-resources-local.html#protecting-local

Comment: This link is now outdated.